# MongoDB DBRef ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: foreign-keys, mongodb, cascade, dbref

Is there a way in MongoDB to have a foreign key with a 'ON DELETE CASCADE' functionality?

I know you can use DBRef as a sort of foreign key but when the item in a collection where the reference points to is removed, the reference returns null. But i want that the item where the reference belongs to gets removed. How do i do this?

Or do i need every time i remove things check references to it?

Comment: finally, have you implemented CASCADE DELETE for MongoDB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This feature doesn't exist now. If you want it. Add it on MongoDB Bugtracker

http://jira.mongodb.org

Comment: I posted a feature request on jira, thnx for the tip ;)

Comment: yeah, srry, i forgot because i had to leave my pc at that moment :P

Comment: Can you provide a link to this issue?

Comment: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1298

Comment: The feature request was rejected in 2015, before transactions were possible. I created a new feature request: https://feedback.mongodb.com/forums/924280-database/suggestions/46728697-cascading-delete-for-dbrefs

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin **DELETE CASCADE** but you can write your own login. Here is mine

```
Category.post('findOneAndDelete', async document => {
  if (document) await Stock.findOneAndDelete({ categoryId: document._id });
});
```

Details: I have to remove stock item if category will delete. So I use `post middleware` on Category delete and in that middleware i find the Stock Item which have that category and remove that too.